# Sort strings of 2d list by sum of elements

Tags: python

I need to find sum of elements that are **even** and **>0** in each string of 2d list

and then sort string of the 2d list by this sum

**Example:**

[image]

**output:**

[image]

There is my code, it doesn't sort strings of 2d list:

```
def findCharacteristicNumber(matrix, row, cols):
characteristicNumber = 0
for j in range(cols):
    if(matrix[row][j] % 2 == 0 and matrix[row][j] > 0):
        characteristicNumber += matrix[row][j]

def task(matrix, rows, cols):
for i in range(rows):
    matrix.sort(key=findCharacteristicNumber(
        matrix, i, cols), reversed=True)
```

i am beginner in python,help me please!I need any way to do that!

Comment: Please do not use images. Remove them and add the data as **text**. Make sure the text you add is a VALID python code.

Comment: @balderman id doesn't matter, it is just an example.How text input will help you?

Comment: you'll be more likely to get help if you provide all information to reproduce your problem.

Comment: We need your input list. I dont get why you are talking about string.

Comment: it matters... I don't have time to make a 2-dim list to help you. By the way `findCharacteristicNumber` return `None`. Do you get an error message? What is your output?

Comment: ... also formatting the code properly it matters

Comment: @Pavel Help us to help you.. Do what we have asked you.

Comment: posting proper formatted code in text is easier for others to copy your code directly to their environment, then run and test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you are calling the 2d list strings when it seems to be numbers. Here a guess of what you want:

```
matrix = [[10, 4, 0], [-7, 0, -1], [8, 8, 8]]
matrix.sort(key=lambda row: sum(i for i in row if i > 0 and i % 2 == 0), reverse=True)
print(matrix)
```

Output:

```
[[8, 8, 8], [10, 4, 0], [-7, 0, -1]]
```

Explanation:

`key` argument is getting each item in matrix which is a row, then `sum()` with the comprehension will return the sum of positive even numbers in that row. After that, sort rows in descending order of sum by `reverse` argument not `reversed`.